# Window.onclick not working in modal box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a modal box of html inside a php foreach loop. I am using javascript to display and hide the modal box by using onclick event. The Problem is bot my onclick event to display and hide functions are working, but when I click on the window outside the modal box it's not hiding the modal box.

I think It might be because I an printing several modal box in the php loop and the javascript does not know which one to close.

I just want to close all the modal box but don't know how to get it done

Thanks in advance

My javascript:

```
<script>
// Get the modal
var currentIndex;
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
    function display(index) {
            modal[index].style.display = "block";
        currentIndex = index;
    } 

function notdisplay(index){
        modal[index].style.display = "none";

    }

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it


window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal[currentIndex]) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}

</script>
```

My modal box inside the php loop:

```
<div class="col-md-7 offset-md-2 myBtn" onclick="display('.$index.')" style="margin-left:20px;">
<span onclick="notdisplay('.$index.')" class="close">&times;</span>
```

Comment: `modal[index].style.display` vs `modal.style.display` spot the difference

Comment: I have tried modal[index] as well, but because index is not defined it throws an error of undefined index.Thank you

Comment: Yes because you don't provide it an index. Which is what you need to do, or simply close them all.

Comment: I was trying to close them all, but each attempt was a failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give access to the index by declare a global variable (let's say var currentIndex) of the script. Then inside display(index) method change the global variable to index.

```
var currentIndex;
function display(index) {
        modal[index].style.display = "block";
        currentIndex = index;

}
```

then inside window.onclick function you can access the currentIndex

```
window.onclick = function(event) {

    if (event.target == modal[currentIndex]) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: but, the problem is when I implement this answer in my window onclick function it doesn't work.

Comment: property of display is undefined is the error in the console

Comment: Once you declare the global variable you do not have to pass it in window.onclick function.

Comment: I have updated the way you wanted,but still got an error?